# Redirect .html request from Apache server to Tomcat server

Tags: java, apache, .htaccess, tomcat

Our web server is a combination of Apache http server and Tomcat server. When ever any request comes, first it will handled by Apache server.If it is type of **.html** or **.htm** or **.log** etc., then the Apache server will process it. If the request is type of **.jsp**, Apache will pass the request to Tomcat server and Tomcat server will process the request.

I deployed a java web application in Tomcat which having some servelt mapping for **.html** and **.log**. Since the Apache http server having the configuration to handle **.html**, the given request is not passed to Tomcat server.

I checked with our Admin, they confirmed me that, i can create a **.htaccess** file in the root directory, which having the configuration to ignore or redirect the **.html** request from being handled by Apache http server.

Is any one know what is the command/configuration i need to add in the **.htaccess** file ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you use mod_jk: take a look here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html#s73 to forward requests to your tomcat instance.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Since i dont have any access to server, this solution wont help us(even though the solution is perfect ). Do you have any idea how this can be done using .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

mod_jk is the one to use for this purpose.

You can also use Apache mod_proxy. Read the Warning at the beginning of the page carefully.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html